# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 328:

Tags: python, sockets, cloud, file-transfer

Ok so I was working on making a cloud storage for my house but the problem is that it receives only .txt or files which have text only. I want it to receive zip files images and all types of files but when I'm trying to send a zip file or any other kind of file type... I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Workspace\Code\Cloud Storage\client.py", line 45, in <module>
    file_data = in_file.read()
  File "C:\Users\Shashankh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 328: character maps to <undefined>
```

i do receive the file but the file is either corrupted or empty.

this is my code.

`client.py`

```py
import socket
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os



s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.0.108',4321))


root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

while True:
   confirm_send = pyautogui.confirm("Do you want to start file transfer?")
   if confirm_send == 'OK':
       warning = pyautogui.confirm("WARNING!: IF YOU HAVE ALREADY SENT THE FILE WITH THE SAME NAME... THE DATA MAY OVERWRITE AND MAY GET CORRUPTED. CHANGE YOUR FILENAME FOR SAFETY!")

       if warning == 'OK':

           prompt = pyautogui.prompt(text='Cloud Name', title='' , default='Enter your cloud storage folder name')
           if prompt == 'Shashankh':
               s.send(bytes('Shashankh','utf-8'))
           if prompt == 'Hari':
               s.send(bytes('Hari','utf-8'))
           if prompt == 'Eshitha':
               s.send(bytes('Eshitha','utf-8'))
           if prompt == 'Prasanna':
               s.send(bytes('Prasanna','utf-8'))
           
           if prompt == None:
               exit()

           file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
           if file == 'Cancel':
               quit()

           file_name = os.path.basename(file)
           s.send(bytes(file_name,'utf-8'))
           open_file = (file, 'rb')        

           with open(file) as in_file:
               file_data = in_file.read()
               s.send(bytes(file_data,'utf-8'))                     
               
           pyautogui.alert("File Transferred succefully!!")
       
       if warning == 'Cancel':
           exit()

   if confirm_send == 'Cancel':
       quit()
   break
```

`server.py`

```py
import socket
import pyautogui
from pyautogui import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
from infi.systray import SysTrayIcon

systray = SysTrayIcon("cloud.ico", "Cloud Storage")
systray.start()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0',4321))
s.listen(5)

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connecting from {address} has been established")

    #getting folder name
    msg0 = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    folder_name = (msg0.decode('utf-8'))

    #getting file name
    msg = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    file_name = (msg.decode("utf-8"))

    #getting file data
    msg2 = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    file_data = msg2.decode('utf-8')

    #checking folder name
    if folder_name == 'Shashankh':
        a = open(f"D:\\Cloud Storage\\Shashankh\\{file_name}", "wb")
        a.write(bytes(file_data,'utf-8'))
        a.close()

    elif folder_name == 'Eshitha':
        a = open(f"D:\\Cloud Storage\\Eshitha\\{file_name}", "wb")
        a.write(file_data)
        a.close()    

    elif folder_name == 'Hari':
        a = open(f"D:\\Cloud Storage\\Hari\\{file_name}", "wb")
        a.write(file_data)
        a.close()

    elif folder_name == 'Prasanna':
        a = open(f"D:\\Cloud Storage\\Prasanna\\{file_name}", "wb")
        a.write(file_data)
        a.close()


    pyautogui.alert("File recieved successfully! | Either you have recieved a file or Transfer has been aborted by user |")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all amazing programme!

It seems that you have missed a keyword in line 45 in your client.py file. as follows
`s.send(bytes(file_name,'utf-8'))`
You have to mention a parameter known as encoding. this will access the encoding format (i,e utf-8) So here is the corrected code below..
 `s.send(bytes(file_name,encoding='utf-8'))`

Hope it works. I would love to see it work.

Comment: Hi!
thanks for the appriciation. the problem i was having wasn't about the file name i.e `somefile.zip`

the prob was sending the file. when i send a zip file i get that error, also please check my code again.. i have edited it. Thank you!